# How to return error from Rxjava Flowable when using LiveDataReactiveStreams?

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-livedata

I am trying to return error from Rxjava stream but it shows error in return type.

Here is the code.

```
    private fun getCategories(): Flowable<Resource<List<Category>>> {
        return shopRepo.getCategories()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .onErrorReturn { Resource.error(it.message) }
            .doOnSubscribe { Resource.loading(true) }
            .map{
                Resource.success(it)
            }
    }

    fun observeCategories(): LiveData<Resource<List<Category>>> {
        return LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(getCategories())
    }

}
```

Here is my Resource Class

```
data class Resource<out T>(val status: Status, val data: T?, val message: String?) {
    enum class Status {
        SUCCESS,
        ERROR,
        LOADING
    }
    companion object {
        fun <T> success(data: T?): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(SUCCESS, data, null)
        }

        fun <T> error(msg: String, data: T?): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(ERROR, data, msg)
        }

        fun <T> loading(data: T?): Resource<T> {
            return Resource(LOADING, data, null)
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to find any reference regarding this issue.

Comment: throw an exception?

Comment: `onErrorReturn` would expect return type same as that of `shopRepo.getCategories()`. If you move the chain call for onErrorReturn after `map`, it should probably work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onErrorReturn` would expect return type same as that of `shopRepo.getCategories()`.

If you move the chain call for onErrorReturn after `map`, it would work as the map will transform the type.

```
shopRepo.getCategories()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map{ Resource.success(it) }
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // You'll need this probably to move it the UI thread.
        .onErrorReturn { Resource.error(it.message) }
        .doOnSubscribe { Resource.loading(true) }
```

Comment: Resource.loading is not working. In the fragment I am checking the status for loading but it is not working.

Comment: It's hard to say why it doesn't work from this code.